# Adding class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am having some issues adding a class on hover. I have the basics of it down, but my end result isn't what I am looking for.

On hover over `profile-pic-container` I am looking for the `profile-pic-hover` to only come up 30% of the height, from the bottom of `profile-pic-container`. Also I cannot figure out how to set the `#profile-pic-change` to display on this hover as well.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('#profile-pic-container').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('profile-pic-hover') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('profile-pic-hover') }
)
```

```css
#profile-pic-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
} 
.profile-pic-hover {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
}
#profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-pic-container">
  <div id="profile-pic-change">Change picture</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all? `#profile-pic-container:hover {}`

Comment: also `profile-pic-hover` and `profile-pic-container` are the same element so  ... *to only come up 30% of the height, from the bottom of profile-pic-container* .... will not work as you think with your actual css code

Comment: Then what could I do to have it only come up 30%.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfbpoefm/

Comment: @DaniP That is perfect! Leave an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another rule to set it to be visible.

```
.profile-pic-hover #profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

but there is no reason to use JavaScript here simple :hover in the CSS and you can style the elements.

```css
#profile-pic-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#profile-pic-container:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#profile-pic-container:hover #profile-pic-change {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-pic-container">
  <div id="profile-pic-change">Change picture</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I get the black background element to only come up 30% of the height of the container?

Answer (score 1):

`id` selector is more specific than `class` selector, for overwrite the properties you can add the id selector to the class or add `!important` keyword:

```
#profile-pic-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}   
#profile-pic-container.profile-pic-hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
#profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

With `!important`:

```
#profile-pic-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}   
.profile-pic-hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 30% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    bottom: 0;
}
#profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: If you have control over all of the css then using `!important` should never be needed and used. You should use `!important` only as a last resort, but always keep in mind that it is a fishy solution. And even if you dont have controll over all  css code then specializing with e.g. a`ID` prefix should solve most problems. `!important` is most of the time only needed if you need to deal with css code that you cannot change and that already uses `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using only CSS, with transition property. change profile pic link can be displayed using hover property

```css
#profile-pic-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
  transition: height 1s;
} 
.profile-pic-hover {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
}

#profile-pic-change {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#profile-pic-container:hover {
  height: calc(200px*(30/100)); 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#profile-pic-container:hover #profile-pic-change {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile-pic-container">
  <div id="profile-pic-change">Change picture</div>
</div>
```